# Unknown item in my startup (sshnas21.dll)

Tags: windows, virus, boot, malware, trojan

I just noticed that I have an unknown item in my Startup in msconfig
the command is

```
rundll32.exe C:\Windows\system32\sshnas21.dll,GetMainWnd
```

what is this?

Comment: What makes you think it's linked to Halo 2?

Comment: @Gnoupi that's just a way of saying stuff :), it never did made me think it linked to the game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **sshnas.dll or sshnas21.dll is a component of trojan FakeAlert**. The trojan come from malicious websites that ask users to download an Adobe Flash Player update or player needed to view a movie online. The filename of the trojan is flash-HQ-plugin. Once started, the trojan will download and install core components: c.exe, msa.exe and sshnas.dll (sshnas21.dll). When downloaded, it will be configured to start automatically when Windows starts. Trojan FakeAlert may display many popups and fake security alerts, hijack Internet Explorer, disable Windows Task Manager and Registry editor.Also it is usually installed in conjunction with a rogue antispyware programs.
>
> If your computer is infected, then use these removal instructions below, which will remove sshnas.dll (sshnas21.dll) trojan and other components of trojan FakeAlert for free.

[Rest of article](http://www.myantispyware.com/2009/12/02/how-to-remove-sshnas-dll-trojan-remove-trojan-fakealert/)

[More good advice](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Comment: I have the sshnas21.dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Comment: better advice don't surf the net as admin!